# Append To Current Url Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have two URLs in Django. 
I would like to be able to use them almost as subdirectories.

In my case, I have a table of parts belonging to a job, and in that table, i have buttons that would allow you to open a new URL with details of the part clicked.

This would be the job URL.

```
/view_job/1/
```

and when you click on an item I would like to be able to navigate to.

```
/view_job/1/details/part1
```

Here are the two URLs.

```
url(r'^view_job/([0-9]+)/$', app.views.viewfab, name='view_job'),
url(r'^view_job/([0-9]+)/details/(.+?)$', app.views.viewfabdetail, name='fab_detail')
```

and here is what I'm trying to achieve in the template.

```
<a href="{% url \'fab_detail\'  "job number" record.mark %}">View</a>
```

the problem I am having is.

I want to be able to pass the job number, which is /view_job/->"job number"<- to the template HTML and I have not been able to find out how to do so.

Thanks for any guidance on the subject.

EDIT

Here is the model being used.

```
class Fab(models.Model):
    jobid = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    mark = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    truck = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    load_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    check_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    checker = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    loaded = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    checked = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def viewfab(request,jid):
    job=Job.objects.filter(id=jid)

    part_json=serializers.serialize('json',job)
    jdata=json.loads(part_json)
    ids=[]
    for id in jdata[0]['fields']['_Fab']:
        ids.append(id)
    prts=Fab.objects.filter(id__in=(ids))
    prts=app.model_extender.combinepartqty(prts)
  #where the issue is
    table=FabTable(prts)
  ###
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)

    return render(request,'app/datatable.html',{'table':table})
print("")
```

Comment: Show code for `app.views.viewfab` view.

Comment: @AamirAdnan Okay its there, probably wont be of much use though. Im just not understanding the html template. Ideally id be able to append /details/part1 to my current url.

Comment: You are trying to create the `fab_detail` URL in `datatable.html`, right? You already have the job why don't you pass it in context to `render`?

Comment: @AamirAdnan Im trying to call app.views.viewfabdetail by navigating to that url. That view will the take the contents from the url (job number, part name) and query the database with it. I just want to be able to keep the url the same all the way up until /details/part1 that way when it passes to viewfabdetail, it will have the job number and the part name available.

Comment: You misunderstood my question, i am asking in which template you are trying to do `<a href="{% url \'fab_detail\'  "job number" record.mark %}">View</a>`

Comment: @AamirAdnan sorry. It is passed to a djangotables2 column which is supposed to make a link to /view_job/"jobnumber"/details/"partname" and then eventually passed to the datatable.html template.